# Custom enum attribute gives error String types not allowed

Tags: java, android, xml, enums, textview

Hello guys I am trying to implement a custom TextView with typeface. I've decided to use RobotoTextView. I have as well fonts folder in the assets. I've got error on line where i've got `**custom:typeface="robotoLight"**`.

The Error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"String types not allowed (at
>   \u0027typeface\u0027 with value
>   \u0027robotoLight\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"path/to/file/thisxml.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":33,"startOffset":1357,"endColumn":44,"endOffset":1368}}],"original":""}

Any help would be appreciated.

My layout with custom TextView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.name"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99f9fafa"
        android:padding="0dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#99f9fafa"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bigImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/noproperty"/>

            <utils.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/propertyPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_800"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                custom:typeface="robotoLight"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/main_purple"/>
        <!--android:background="@color/main_color_500" />-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the attribute file with styleable:

```
<declare-styleable name="RobotoTextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="enum">
        <enum name="robotoBlack" value="0" />
        <enum name="robotoBlackItalic" value="1" />
        <enum name="robotoBold" value="2" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldItalic" value="3" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldCondensed" value="4" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldCondensedItalic" value="5" />
        <enum name="robotoCondensed" value="6" />
        <enum name="robotoCondensedItalic" value="7" />
        <enum name="robotoItalic" value="8" />
        <enum name="robotoLight" value="9" />
        <enum name="robotoLightItalic" value="10" />
        <enum name="robotoMedium" value="11" />
        <enum name="robotoMediumItalic" value="12" />
        <enum name="robotoRegular" value="13" />
        <enum name="robotoThin" value="14" />
        <enum name="robotoThinItalic" value="15" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

My class with the Custom Text View
    public class RobotoTextView extends TextView {

```
    public RobotoTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        parseAttributes(null);
    }

    public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    private void parseAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
        int typeface;
        if (attrs == null) { //Not created from xml
            typeface = Roboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR;
        } else {
            TypedArray values = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RobotoTextView);
            typeface = values.getInt(R.styleable.RobotoTextView_typeface, Roboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR);
            values.recycle();
        }
        setTypeface(getRoboto(typeface));
    }

    public void setRobotoTypeface(int typeface) {
        setTypeface(getRoboto(typeface));
    }

    private Typeface getRoboto(int typeface) {
        return getRoboto(getContext(), typeface);
    }

    public static Typeface getRoboto(Context context, int typeface) {
        switch (typeface) {
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BLACK:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBlack == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBlack = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBlack;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BLACK_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBlackItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBlackItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBlackItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BOLD:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBold == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBold;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BOLD_CONDENSED:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensed == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensed = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensed;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BOLD_CONDENSED_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensedItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensedItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBoldCondensedItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_BOLD_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoBoldItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoBoldItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_CONDENSED:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoCondensed == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoCondensed = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Condensed.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoCondensed;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_CONDENSED_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoCondensedItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoCondensedItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-CondensedItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoCondensedItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_LIGHT:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoLight == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoLight;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_LIGHT_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoLightItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoLightItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoLightItalic;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_MEDIUM:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoMedium == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoMedium;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_MEDIUM_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoMediumItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoMediumItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoMediumItalic;
            default:
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoRegular == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoRegular;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_THIN:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoThin == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoThin = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoThin;
            case Roboto.ROBOTO_THIN_ITALIC:
                if (Roboto.sRobotoThinItalic == null) {
                    Roboto.sRobotoThinItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf");
                }
                return Roboto.sRobotoThinItalic;
        }
    }

    public static class Roboto {
        public static final int ROBOTO_BLACK = 0;
        public static final int ROBOTO_BLACK_ITALIC = 1;
        public static final int ROBOTO_BOLD = 2;
        public static final int ROBOTO_BOLD_ITALIC = 3;
        public static final int ROBOTO_BOLD_CONDENSED = 4;
        public static final int ROBOTO_BOLD_CONDENSED_ITALIC = 5;
        public static final int ROBOTO_CONDENSED = 6;
        public static final int ROBOTO_CONDENSED_ITALIC = 7;
        public static final int ROBOTO_ITALIC = 8;
        public static final int ROBOTO_LIGHT = 9;
        public static final int ROBOTO_LIGHT_ITALIC = 10;
        public static final int ROBOTO_MEDIUM = 11;
        public static final int ROBOTO_MEDIUM_ITALIC = 12;
        public static final int ROBOTO_REGULAR = 13;
        public static final int ROBOTO_THIN = 14;
        public static final int ROBOTO_THIN_ITALIC = 15;

        private static Typeface sRobotoBlack;
        private static Typeface sRobotoBlackItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoBold;
        private static Typeface sRobotoBoldItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoBoldCondensed;
        private static Typeface sRobotoBoldCondensedItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoCondensed;
        private static Typeface sRobotoCondensedItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoLight;
        private static Typeface sRobotoLightItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoMedium;
        private static Typeface sRobotoMediumItalic;
        private static Typeface sRobotoRegular;
        private static Typeface sRobotoThin;
        private static Typeface sRobotoThinItalic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.name"
```

is the old style of adding a custom namespace. Try using the following which automatically substitutes the correct package for you --

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: This helped me and after cleaning the project everything works as it should. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

Change your following code

```
<declare-styleable name="RobotoTextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="enum">
        <enum name="robotoBlack" value="0" />
        <enum name="robotoBlackItalic" value="1" />
        <enum name="robotoBold" value="2" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldItalic" value="3" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldCondensed" value="4" />
        <enum name="robotoBoldCondensedItalic" value="5" />
        <enum name="robotoCondensed" value="6" />
        <enum name="robotoCondensedItalic" value="7" />
        <enum name="robotoItalic" value="8" />
        <enum name="robotoLight" value="9" />
        <enum name="robotoLightItalic" value="10" />
        <enum name="robotoMedium" value="11" />
        <enum name="robotoMediumItalic" value="12" />
        <enum name="robotoRegular" value="13" />
        <enum name="robotoThin" value="14" />
        <enum name="robotoThinItalic" value="15" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

to this

```
<declare-styleable name="RobotoTextView"> 
     <attr name="typeface" />
</declare-styleable>

<attr name="typeface" format="enum">
    <enum name="robotoBlack" value="0" />
    <enum name="robotoBlackItalic" value="1" />
    <enum name="robotoBold" value="2" />
    <enum name="robotoBoldItalic" value="3" />
    <enum name="robotoBoldCondensed" value="4" />
    <enum name="robotoBoldCondensedItalic" value="5" />
    <enum name="robotoCondensed" value="6" />
    <enum name="robotoCondensedItalic" value="7" />
    <enum name="robotoItalic" value="8" />
    <enum name="robotoLight" value="9" />
    <enum name="robotoLightItalic" value="10" />
    <enum name="robotoMedium" value="11" />
    <enum name="robotoMediumItalic" value="12" />
    <enum name="robotoRegular" value="13" />
    <enum name="robotoThin" value="14" />
    <enum name="robotoThinItalic" value="15" />
 </attr>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Not sure that there's any difference between my code and yours :)

Comment: @user1870076 Once change the `xmlns:custom` tag to this `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and try.